# WIA Scan, change multiple properties

Tags: c#, scanning, wia

I am currently working on an application that is supposed to scan images. It does scan those images successfully, but when trying to change the scan properties of the device it only ever uses the last changed property.

My current code for changing the properties is as follows:

```
public static string Scan()
{
    WIA.Device scanner = ScannerManager.Scanner.Connect();
    IItem scannerItem = scanner.Items[1];
    AdjustWiaSettings(scannerItem);
    ImageFile imageFile = (ImageFile)scannerItem.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatTIFF);
    return SaveScannedFile(imageFile);
}

private static void AdjustWiaSettings(IItem scannerItem)
{
    const string WIA_SCAN_COMPRESSION = "4107"; // valid values: 0,5,8
    const string WIA_SCAN_COLORING = "6146"; //4 is Black-white, 2 is gray, 1 is color
    SetWiaProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_COMPRESSION, 5);
    SetWiaProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_COLORING, 4);
}

private static void SetWiaProperty(IProperties properties, object propName, object propValue)
{
    Property prop = properties.get_Item(ref propName);
    prop.set_Value(ref propValue);
}
```

It only changes the coloring property of the the two, but if the two SetWiaProperty functions are switched, it only changes the compression property.

I have tried a different approach iterating over all the properties, but that yielded the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was only partially with WIA. The setting of WIA properties appear to need to be in order of property. If done correctly, the outgoing scan file in the example above is around 1 MB in size (down from 30+ MB).

The real issue was MagickImage that I used to convert the file into a .pdf. I only ever checked that .pdf file without ever checking the result of the scan itself. The resulting filesize made me believe only one property was used, when infact MagickImage with the basic inputs without altering any properties for the converting method increased the file size from 1MB to 13 MB per page.